# Library that defaults scrollbar to always be fully scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, scrollbar

I'm making an Electron app (pure html, js, css).
I need my div's scrollbar to be fully scrolled by default.

I already have a function that scrolls to bottom whenever I call it:

```
function updateScroll() {
    var height=$("#chatArea").height();
    $("#chatWrapper").animate({ scrollTop: height }, "fast");
}
```

It works, but... I add new content with animations and constantly calling the scrolldown function just ends up looking laggy. It would be much better if the scrollbar was always on bottom.

I was wondering if there is maybe a (npm) library that I can include and use to force the scrollbar to be fully scrolled by default (but user can still scroll up-down)..

Does anyone have experience with this?
Thank you.. :-)

Comment: So are u asking for a library?

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW I am asking if anyone has experience with this and how I can make the scrollbar fully scrolled by default. Since I didn't find a way to do this with simple html, js, css then yes, I am asking if anyone knows about a js library or something... I assumed someone had to have had a similar issue

Comment: If so, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm not asking for recommendation, I'm asking for a solution. I don't know how to make it fully scrolled by default, I don't need to choose someone's opinion, I need a solution.